# How does the relying party know where to redirect to after obtaining the access token?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

Looking at the steps at http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

1. The RP (Client) sends a request to the OpenID Provider (OP).
2. The OP authenticates the End-User and obtains authorization.
3. The OP responds with an ID Token and usually an Access Token.
4. The RP can send a request with the Access Token to the UserInfo Endpoint.
5. The UserInfo Endpoint returns Claims about the End-User.

I am not sure I understand how after 4. the relying party would know to redirect to the original URL the user attempted to access.I would think there would be a query parameter passed around during the redirects but the protocol does not seem to explicitly define any such parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The authorize endpoint supports the `state` parameter which is echoed back as-is in the callback. Typically the value passed would be a serialized and protected (signed and possibly encrypted) string containing any information you need to preserve during the roundtrip. Inside that payload could be the URL that was originally requested.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) instead it seems that the redirect URI is indeed passed around as a query parameter.